# how to create a plugin with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Hi everyone I am trying to call a ajax function in my plugin, for this I saw this 
[tutorial](http://pippinsplugins.com/using-ajax-your-plugin-wordpress-admin/)  But in my case never execute de ajax call.

First in the constructor I have this:

```
  function __construct(){
    add_action('init', array( $this, 'register_script'));
     ....
    add_action('wp_ajax_aad_get_results', array($this, 'aad_process_ajax'));

  }



  function register_script(){
   wp_register_script('myplugin', plugins_url('/includes/myplugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
   wp_enqueue_script('myplugin');
   wp_enqueue_script('add-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/js/add-ajax.js', array('jquery'));

  }
```

this function has to execute when I click in the buttom of this form

```
  public function rbk_show_box( $post ) {

    // get post meta values
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );          
    // echo '<input type="hidden" name="',$post->post_title.'_add_box_nonce" value="',wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)),'" />';
      echo '<form id="camposMeta" name="este" method="POST">';
      echo'</form>';
      echo '<form id="camposMeta" name="este" method="POST" >';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="',$post->post_title,'">';
      echo '<fieldset id="campos1" class="clonedInput">';
      echo '<label>Name</label>';
      echo '<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />';
      echo '<select name="select1" id="select1">';
      echo '<option >Selecciona el tipo</option>';
      echo '<option>Text</option>';
      echo '<option>TextArea</option>';
      echo '<option>File</option>';
      echo '</select>';
      echo'</fieldset>';
      echo '<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" />';
      echo'<input type= "submit" id="btn_submit" value="Crear Meta Box">';
    echo'</form>';
  }
```

I create dynamic field in my form so now I need take all this field to create a metabook.

I know that a take my field  like this:`$('#camposMeta').serialize()` but when I call the file `createMetaBox.php` to pass this params the program don't work!!

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function(){
        alert('ready')
        $.ajax({
            // url: createMetaBox.php
            data: {
                action: 'aad_get_results',
                //valores:$('#camposMeta').serialize()

            },
            success:function(){
            }
        });
    });
```

any idea!!!

Comment: So it's not alerting ready? Also, @RRikesh is right, you're using the same form id twice.  Have you tried using form submit instead of click?  That way you cater for keyboard users too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OO techniques, I suspect that your ajax hook should be like:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_aad_get_results', array( $this, 'aad_process_ajax' ) );
```

If you want the Ajax to execute for users who are not logged in(for example front end), you should also add:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_aad_get_results', array( $this, 'aad_process_ajax' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks @RRikesh I modified the call method but the response is null. When I click in the butom execute this /wp-admin/post.php?post=102&action=edit&action=aad_get_results    but the result is empty

Comment: Hi @RRikesh I change my question, I put all my code I finally I saw my file.js but never call the ajax function. any idea!! Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot @Imaginate but I don't know why in my case never call the ajax function

Comment: Why are there two form tags with the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

You have to post to the ajax url.

First localize your javascript after enqueing it, and make the ajaxurl available as a variable

```
wp_localize_script( 'quote_script', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Then call your ajax with the ajax url variable

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl;
    data: {
    action: 'aad_get_results',
    },
```

Also, if you echo from your php function, you'll need to do something with it in the ajax callback, eg

```
    success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
               };
```